# AWS: Mapping domain on S3 Static content as well as api gateway endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to achieve the following domain/path mappings:

foo.com -> static web content hosted in AWS S3

foo.com/dogs -> api gateway endpoint

foo.com/cats -> api gateway endpoint

foo.com/birds -> api gateway endpoint

What service(s) do I need to use to achieve the above?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options for this. Since you want a single hostname, foo.com, you need to start with a single service that can direct client traffic to s3 and to api gateway.

Option1: [Amazon Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)

This one has the benefit of scale.

```
              | -> S3
cloudfront -> |
              | -> api gateway
```

[How to setup cloudfront for API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/)

[How to seutp cloudfront with S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)

And since you have cloudfront you might want to see if you can use [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/).

Option 2: [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/)

If you don't have a lot of experience with AWS service or even if you do this is a good option I would recommend looking at first as it simplifies a lot of the setup for you and has some nice [features] (https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/features/). Think of Amplify as service of services for application developers.

Check out (Amplify API)[https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api] which is used for creating REST or GraphQL endpoints.

I should mention what frameworks Amplify support: iOS, Android, ReactNative, and for web it has deep integration with React, Ionic, Angular, and Vue.js.

And yes, you will probably end up with same solution using Amplify as Option 1 it is which workflow works best for you.

Option 3 split the service:

Create 2 DNS entries for foo.com and api.foo.com

```
          | -> (foo.com) cloundfront -> S3
client -> |
          | -> (api.food.com) api-gateway
```

You could remove cloudfront in this solution and just use [S3 static](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

Note on Route53:  You do not need to use Route53 as any DNS service will work.  If you go with option 1 cloudfront it's just as easy to create the CNAME in any DNS services.  However, if you are using Amplify then then moving your DNS service to AWS Route53 will automate you DNS management.

Answer (score -2):

AWS services required for the above requirements:

1. Route 53
2. S3
3. API Gateway

Comment: Which service would be used to define the mappings?

Comment: API Gateway can have /dogs /birds /cats . are you referring to this?

Comment: I know that i can define api gateway resources for /dogs, /cats, /birds but I need to find the place where I can do the DNS/path mappings ad outlines above.

Comment: Define the resources in API gateway and map the API default path to the domain in Route 53